# SQL Server 2012: Generated Text File Adds Hidden Characters

Tags: sql-server, text, ascii, flat-file

I am attempting to create a flat file to send to another party. The problem is that when it is created in SQL and sent via email, it adds hidden characters. Opening the text file in notepad, you cannot see them.

[image: Appears okay]

If you open it via command line with:

```
edit test.txt
```

It adds a ton of spaces and other funky characters.

[image]

If I manually create a blank text file and copy my query results into the file, the characters do not exist. I spoke with the consumer of the file. He noted that it must not be in standard ASCII format but I can't seem to figure out how to determine what format the file is created in.

I'd like to keep the process automated without having to manually create files or push them through converters.

Any thoughts?

Edit:

Here's how the file is created:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail

@profile_name                   =   'test',
@recipients                     =   'test@test.com',
@subject                        =   'Flat File Test', 
@body                           =   'test',
@query                          =   '
                                    set nocount on;
                                    select      ''DO*J!*'' + convert( varchar,getdate(),112 )
                                    select      Dtl
                                    from        ##flatFile
                                    order by    Id,
                                                Ln
                                    ',
@attach_query_result_as_file    =   1,
@query_attachment_filename      =   'test.txt',
@query_result_header            =   0,
@query_result_no_padding        =   1
```

Comment: How exactly ARE you creating the text file?  What does "when it is created in SQL " mean?

Comment: By "funky characters" do you mean the New Line? That is how the text file knows you have a carriage return... how else would it display the end of the row? Copy that data into Notepad++ and turn on all characters and see what you've got. Console isn't a great place to edit text files.

Comment: Tab - File is created via the sp_send_dbmail procedure

Comment: You still haven't told us what "funky" characters you have--and if they are actually improper. You can find this information through many methods and without it we can't help you.

Comment: Jacob - the music notes and the box at the top left of the file, along with all the spaces are causing the issues. Perhaps the music note represents a line break. How would I change that to be blank but still have a break?

Comment: Apparently, your file is saved as [`UTF-16` \(or `UCS-2`\)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) with [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) however I'm not sure about [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Comment: You can determine what format the file is created in by opening it in some [hex editor](https://www.google.com/search?q=hex+editor).

Comment: Josef - Where would I change the save format within SQL?

Comment: Let SQL as is. Stop using  `edit.com` because it's a 16-bit program (a 1990's tool but we are in 2017).